# State update not reflecting in custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using `react-redux` to store a state `modeData` which is an array of objects. Using `react-hotkeys-hook`, when the user presses `ctrl+l`, a function runs which updates the state. In that same function, when I `console.log` the same state, it does not reflect the changes. 
Here's the code I'm using:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { modeDataIncrement } from "./redux/modeSlice";
import { useHotkeys } from "react-hotkeys-hook";
import { useEffect } from "react";

//..

const modeData = useSelector((state) => state.mode.modeData);  //array of objects.

const handler = (id) => {
    const isActive = modeData.find((x) => x.id === id).active;
    console.log(modeData);      // does not show the updated state
    dispatch(modeDataIncrement(id));
  };


useHotkeys("ctrl+l", () => handler("Clone"));

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(modeData);  //working fine!
  }, [modeData]);
```

`modeSlice.js`:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const modeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "mode",
  initialState: {
    modeData: [{ id: "Clone", active: false }],
  },
  reducers: {
    modeDataIncrement: (state, action) => {
      state.modeData.find(
        (e) => e.id === action.payload && (e.active = !e.active)
      );
    },
  },
});

export const { modeDataIncrement } = modeSlice.actions;
export default modeSlice.reducer;
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs to use the latest version of modeData, but based on the [source code of useHotkeys](https://github.com/JohannesKlauss/react-hotkeys-hook/blob/master/src/useHotkeys.ts), it will memoize the function, and not update it automatically. So you're always using the version of the callback that existed on the first render.

To fix this, you need to pass a dependency array in to useHotkeys, so it can break the memoization:

```
const handler = (id) => {
  const isActive = modeData.find((x) => x.id === id).active;
  console.log(modeData); 
  dispatch(modeDataIncrement(id));
};

useHotkeys("ctrl+l", () => handler("Clone"), [modeData]);
```

Comment: Whoa! Thanks! That worked. I didn't know that we can pass a dependency array in to useHotkeys